# Converting From MYSQL Point to Swift CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: php, mysql, swift, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm working on an application which retrieves locations from a MYSQL database as a Point type.  One of the parameters to create a custom object is a CLLocationCoordinate2D.  I've been unsuccessful in figuring out how the Point type works after it was JSON encoded from my server. I haven't been able to find any helpful documentation on what is returned or a way to convert from a MYSQL point to a Swift CLLocationCoordinate2D and was wondering if anyone else has had experience with this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of searching, I have a solution that is working.  Not sure if it's the best way, but it works.

Since MYSQL Point is store as (longitude latitude) (NO COMMA), I was able to issue a select statement

```
SELECT X(Column Name), Y(Column Name) from TABLE_NAME
```

which in return gave me each of the values.  From there, I used

```
(jsonElement as! NSString).doubleValue
```

to create CLLocationDegrees for the points, which are needed in order to create a CLLocationCoordinate2D.  If anyone else has found a better or more efficient solution, I would love to hear.  Thanks